# Templates class connect

Tags: c++, templates, qobject

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Form* form = new Form;
    Form1* form1 = new Form1;

    obj = new MyObj<Form>(form);

    emit mySig(form1);
    emit mySig(form);
}
```

myobject.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include "form.h"
#include "form1.h"

class MyObjBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyObjBase() {}

private slots:
    virtual void mySlot(Form* f) = 0;
    virtual void mySlot(Form1* f) = 0;

signals:
    void mySig(Form* f);
    void mySig(Form1* f);
};

template <typename T>
class MyObj : public MyObjBase
{
public:
    MyObj(T* obj) : MyObjBase()
    {
        this->obj = obj;
        connect(this,SIGNAL(mySig(T*)),this,SLOT(mySlot(Form*)));
    }

    T* obj = NULL;

    void mySlot(Form* f) {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }
    void mySlot(Form1* f) {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

    void emitSig() {
        emit mySig(obj);
    }
};
```

Why is the connect not working? I thought when i specialize my template class via <> when i initialize it, that the compiler creates new code for that class where T = Form. Then the connect should work in my opinion :D

Get a generic connect like that working would make my code shorter.

It compiles fine but the output is:

> QObject::connect: No such signal MyObjBase::mySig(T*) in
>   ..\overload_signals\myobj.h:30

thank you for helping me

Comment: Mixing QObject, moc and class templates need special care. See https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq15-academic.html. I haven't read the article fully to give you an answer.

Comment: thanks, do you know why the compiler sees it as T* there?

Comment: I suspect you get that from the MOC, not the C++ compiler.

Comment: yes sry you right. does moc run after the c++ compiler? Does it now have the compiled code from the c++ compiler?

Comment: The MOC runs before the C++ compiler. These basic questions lead me to suggest that you need to grab a book on programming with Qt and spend some time understanding the basics of how to use Qt before diving into creating classes to use with Qt.

Comment: observer pattern works well, but I will go for multiple connects, cause I want the option to not connect one parameter if wanted :). thanks solved

Comment: On the Site See doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq15-academic.html the observerpattern is in my optionion described wrong. I explain why pls tell me if I'm correct. If AnObserver is a templateclass like in the example provided on the site, AnObserver cannot be used like that AnObserver* in the ATemplateClass. Template-arguments are missing there. compiler complains as soon you subclass from AnObserver.